# What am I doing if in the return line i put the name of the class before the returned value?

Tags: python, oop

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.coord = (self.x, self.y)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    p1 = Point(3, 5)
    p2 = Point(7, -2)
    print(p1+p2)    # <__main__.Point object at 0x000001A2DAEF3E20>
```

If i return like this i got this result. (I know this is the memory address)

But if i return like this:

```
return self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y
```

Then I got the actual values (10, 3)

And I don't really understand that I am doing when i type there the name of the class

Comment: This isn't in any way specific to `return`. It's the same as the difference between `(10,3)` and `Point(10,3)` in general. Maybe look at `print(p1)` and `print(p2)`?

Comment: `return <something>` returns a value from your function. `p1 = Point(3, 5)` instantiates a `Point` object and assigns it to var `p1`... `return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)` instantiates a `Point` object and returns it

Comment: BTW, you'd get a more meaningful result if you defined a `__repr__` method to control how your object is coerced into a string.

Comment: You need a `__repr__` for your class. Otherwise this is the default format.

Answer (score 2):

When you type the name of the class, you're invoking the class constructor to construct a new `Point` object:

```
Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

When you remove the `Point()` part, you're just constructing a `tuple`:

```
self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y
```

The `tuple` prints nicely, but it's not a `Point`; if you try to add it to another `tuple` you'll get a concatenated `tuple`:

```
>>> (3, 5) + (7, -2)
(3, 5, 7, -2)
```

and if you try to add it to a `Point` you'll get an error:

```
>>> (3, 5) + Point(7, -2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "Point") to tuple
```

What you might want to do is add a `__str__` and/or `__repr__` method to your `Point` class so that when you print it, you see `x` and `y` rather than the memory address:

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.coord = (self.x, self.y)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Point({self.x}, {self.y})"
```

Now you can return a `Point` object and print it in a way that's more useful:

```
p1 = Point(3, 5)
p2 = Point(7, -2)
print(p1 + p2)    # Point(10, 3)
```

You might also consider using a `dataclass`, which automatically defines `__init__` and `__repr__` in ways that are convenient for this type of use case (I'd also make `coord` a `@property` so you don't need to worry about updating it every time `x` and `y`  change):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int

    @property
    def coord(self):
        return self.x, self.y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

p1 = Point(3, 5)
p2 = Point(7, -2)
print(p1 + p2)    # Point(x=10, y=3)
```

Comment: Maybe `!r` on those so we continue to do the right thing even if x and y are no longer integers?

Comment: I was just about to post about dataclasses

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is this:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.coord = (self.x, self.y)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

p1 = Point(3, 5)
p2 = Point(7, -2)
print(p1+p2)
```

this will return you a Point instance tuple of coord 10, 3

Comment: This is just OP's original code; other than fixing their indentation error, you haven't made any effort to fix their problem or answer the question they asked.